# Easy spam block in Gnus

Tags: emacs, spam-prevention, email-client, gnus

What is the easiest way to block a certain email address from sending you messages in Gnus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way without using external programs or writing dozens lines of elisp code is to use [splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Splitting-Mail.html#Splitting-Mail).

Let's say your spammer is named John Smith after the well-known Time Lord, and you store your mail in a group called `mail.misc`. Just put this in load path:

```
(setq nnmail-split-methods
       '(("mail.spam" "^From:.*John Smith.*")
         ("mail.misc" "")))
```

The second string inside the alist item is a regular expression.